# Получение сообщения о новой записи

Tags: sql, delphi

Делаю небольшую программу (клиентская+серверная часть). Используют программу пользователи и администраторы домена.

У пользователей есть возможность добавлять заявки, у администраторов возможность просматривать и закрывать их. У меня сейчас реализована функция оповещения о новых заявках по следующему алгоритму:

1) Пользователь добавляет новую заявку, ей в поле статус
    присваивается значение 0 - непрочитанная.

2)Каждые 60 секунд (по таймеру) происходит проверка: является ли клиент 
   администратором домена (проверка осуществляется хранимой процедурой на сервере) - если является:

- SQL-запросом просматриваем все непрочитанные заявки (со значением 0).
- Выводим для администратора сообщение о новой заявке.
- Присваиваем заявке статус прочитанной (даем записи значение 1).

Недостатком такого алгоритма является то, что у администраторов программа может быть запущена в разное время, следовательно, отсчет таймера разный, и как только один из администраторов получает оповещение о новой заявке, ей присваивается статус прочитанной и другие админы уже не получают уведомление о новой заявке.

Вопрос следующий: можно ли улучшить данный алгоритм или может быть нужно действовать по-другому? Можно ли как-то синхронизировать таймеры у всех администраторов?

Comment: Вариантов как минимум несколько: можно заставить админа в явном виде сообщать "я прочитал и отреагировал" - проставлять признак "прочитано" по нажатию на кнопку. Можно завести подчиненную таблицу, в которую писать - кто именно получил уведомление. И определять "новая или нет" по отсутствию записи в этой подчиненной таблице.

Comment: Наверное оба варианта не подходят, поскольку я не могу точно знать сколько админов на данный момент будут работать с программой.

Comment: Оба варианта решают озвученную проблему "другие админы не получают уведомление о новой заявке". Они ориентированы на разные технологии работы админов (первый вариант - на "любой из админов должен отреагировать, после чего остальным она не нужна", второй - на "каждый должен увидеть заявку"). А чего хотите добиться вы?

Comment: Хотелось бы, чтобы когда пользователь отправлял заявку, админы в одно время получили уведомление о ней.

Comment: вы чего хотите добавиться то, чтобы все одновременно увидели оповещение, или чтобы оповещение в принципе показалось у всех, а не только у того, кто первый прочитает?
во втором случае, надо не у заявки ставить Прочитано, а делать связь многие-ко-многим для Заявки-Пользователи, где до полем будет "Прочитано"

Comment: А смысл? Даже если вы добьетесь абсолютно синхронного обращения к базе (нереально) - все запросы НЕ будут выполнены одновременно. Что-то выполнится раньше, что-то позже. Вы пытаетесь решить проблему заведомо ошибочным способом.

Comment: Тогда наверное, хотелось бы, чтобы все админы увидели уведомление о заявке

Comment: `Прочитана` это вообще странный статус. статусы могут быть "подана, на рассмотрении, в работе, выполнена", а прочитано, это свойство оповещения вообще

Comment: "хотелось бы, чтобы все админы увидели уведомление о заявке" - тогда вам второй способ.

Comment: Можете поподробней про второй вариант, если можно, то пошагово

Comment: у вас сейчас 2 таблицы 1) `заявки` 2) `пользователи` и когда пользователь видит оповщение вы обновляете таблицу 1. Вам же надо добавить третью таблицу `Оповещения` из `order_id, user_id`. И вот когда кто-то увидел оповещение, то именно в эту третью должна вставится соответствующая строка. А в таблице заявок поле "просмотрено" вообще убрать надо.

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня нет таблицы "Пользователи". Я проверяю, является ли пользователь администратором домена с помощью SQL-функции IS_MEMBER, которая проверяет принадлежит ли пользователь к определенной группе Active Directory

Comment: вообще потенциально сервер сам может уведомлять о событиях,  таких как добавление данных, не надо дергать постоянно селекты по таймеру. зависит от субд, конечно, и готовых компонентов для делфей

Comment: да не важно, ID у пользователя все равно есть. его и пишите в третью таблицу. имя доменной учетки или ее UID.

Comment: вам бы и в приложении сначала определить является ли вообще текущий пользователь админом, а потом ходить за обновлениями по таймеру. а не для всех подряд дергать их.

Comment: @teran "Вам же надо добавить третью таблицу Оповещения из order_id, user_id. И вот когда кто-то увидел оповещение, то именно в эту третью должна вставится соответствующая строка". Из этого вообще ничего не понял

Comment: @e.khamidullin вам нужна отдельная таблица. чтобы отмечать факт прочтения оповещения пользователем. строка такой таблицы по крайней мере должна содержать идентификатор заявки, и пользователя, который ее читает.